# Перенести стиль из body в head Joomla 3.хx

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

Хочу перенести стиль из Body в Head.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

/public_html/modules/mod_as_menu/tmpl/style.php
Сам стиль выполняется тут. А что именно запускает его в Body найти не смог. Подскажите пожалуйста ребята

Comment: а что прописано в styles.php

Comment: К основному сообщению прикрепил вконце

Answer (score 0):

Корректный способ добавления стилей - именно через `head`.

(тогда его могут правильно обрабатывать плагины оптимизации, к примеру)

Пример добавления:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$style = '
    #as-menu ul.as-menu li li:hover ul,
    #as-menu ul.as-menu li li.asHover ul,
    #as-menu ul.as-menu li li li:hover ul,
    #as-menu ul.as-menu li li li.asHover ul
    {
        left: 100px;
    }
';
$document->addStyleDeclaration($style);
```

Соответственно, сформируйте текстовую переменную `$style`, а потом добавьте через `addStyleDeclaration()`.

Документация:

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page#CSS_Examples

Comment: В начале Style.php идет.... <?php
/*******************************************************************************************/
/*
/*  
/*  
/*  
/*
/*******************************************************************************************/
?> Дальше сам стиль $document = JFactory::getDocument();
$style = ' <style>.......</style> '; Я верно делаю?

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста Я правильно понял?

Comment: Как вы сказали сделать не работает. Добавляется не Java а php script

Comment: @НикитаВасильев не совсем так Вы делали.

Comment: @НикитаВасильев
Где именно Вы подтягиваете style.php ?
Где Вам надо вывести стили, на какой странице?
Или на всех? Или на тех, где есть какой-то компонент / модуль?

Comment: Я его если Я правильно понял тяну тут " include 'styles.php';" это в самом конце head. Это стиль всех страниц. Он отвечает за шапку сайта

Comment: @НикитаВасильев, в каком файле и в каком месте файла Вы прописали `include 'styles.php';` ?

Comment: В шаблоне Моем. index.php перед закрыванием тега head

Comment: В коде "Попытка № 2" Вы начинаете прописывать строковую переменную $style_as_menu. Но потом появляется `<?php  if($gradient_topcolor && $gradient_btmcolor): ?>` и ниже `<?php endif; ?>`.
Так задумано? )
И посмотреть бы на index.php, хотя бы - где и как вставляете `include`.

Comment: И ещё. Вы писали выше, что прописываете `include 'styles.php';`
Но в вопросе название файла - `style.php` - без `s` :)

Comment: Я прикреплю в начале весь индекс пхп. Выделил цветом где прописываю инклуд. Я если честно немного запутался сам. Могут быть опечатки не недопонимание с Моей стороны.

Comment: Да вы правы это разные вещи вообще. include 'styles.php' в Хэде. А тогда где подключается вообще этот стиль. Я потерялся что то

Comment: @НикитаВасильев, посмотрел код index.php.

Comment: Дело в том, что Вы подключаете `include 'styles.php';` уже поздно - уже после того, как выведен head строкой `<jdoc:include type="head" />`.
Попробуйте `include 'styles.php';` разместить вверху, 5-й строчкой.

И повторюсь. Проверьте - надо писать `styles.php` ИЛИ `style.php`.

Comment: Смотрите. Я все перепутал "styles.php". Не имеет отношения конкретно к этому вопросу. Проблема в от что Я не могу понять откуда вызывается этот стиль? styles.php это вообще что то другое и к нему вопросов нету. style.php. – вот он в боди вызывается. Откуда Я не могу понять, прямого вызова Я не нашел. Да и воообще намека на его вызов

Comment: @НикитаВасильев, тогда в чем состоит вопрос?

Comment: Обратите Внимания на скришот. класс moduletable-wrapper в нем вызывается стиль. Этот стиль нужно убрать в в Хэд где ему место. Сам стиль нашел по пути /public_html/modules/mod_as_menu/tmpl

Comment: @НикитаВасильев, судя по скриншоту, этот CSS стиль добавляется в модуле. Скорее всего, это модуль типа HTML-код, но может и другой модуль, в код которого внесли правки.
Вероятно, для этого модуля добавлен суффикс CSS класса модуля `navigation` и `span8`.
Также возможно, что это не стандартный модуль HTML-код, а модуль типа Меню, в код которого внесены такие не очень корректные правки.
Вам нужно:
* Найти этот модуль
* Убрать из него прямой вывод HTML-кода со `style`
* Вместо прмого вывода добавить вывод так, как я показал Вам в Ответе.

Comment: Ответ немного сумбурный и не понятный Мне. Давайте разубирать сначала. Я нашел где выполняется этот стиль  /public_html/modules/mod_as_menu/tmpl/style.php в нем код php. Полный стайл пхп прикреплен в конце основного ответа

Comment: "Был добавлен код в style.php Согласно документации. Проблему не решило. Код немного сократил чтобы проще читался" Тут весь код style.php

Comment: _Давайте разубирать сначала_   - Разбирайте - пожалуйста. Я не против :) Всё написано, и даже больше. Знал бы, что ответ будет "сумбурным", не тратил бы время вообще.

Comment: Я совершенно ничего не понял правда.  Что куда и зачем. Если вы понимаете что и откуда, объясните пожалуйста. Форум же и нужен для этого. Если вы знаете и зачем объясните тому кто не знает, это вам только прибавит знания и опыта если вы объясните тому кто не знает. Обычно работает так. А то объяснение выглядит так: берешь это, смотришь там, ну и получаешь это. Готово. Можно работать.